Get values from a struct in an array in ColdFusion
I have an array of a struct that I need to access values like this: every new array, it should just add comma, I tried looping over an array and then struct, but trying to see if there is any easy way
     <cfset stNewColor = StructNew()>
     <cfset stItemNewColors = DeSerializeJson(qAproval.DataJson)>
    
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(stItemNewColors )#" index="i">
          
          <cfset stNewColor ['Item'] = stItemNewColors [i]['Item']>
          
        </cfloop>

This is what I Tried so far.

<cfloop array="#stSlabNewColors#" index="item">
    #item.Product# - #item.NewColor#<br>
</cfloop>

You could use array loop and using the array index, it will be easier.

while this would help, but I Figured out the answer myself, thanks
